# MS SQL Edge running on Docker randomly quits within an hour of starting

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, docker, centos, azure-sql-edge

I set up a new CentOS 7 VM (1GB of RAM, x86-64) and installed the latest version of Docker as instructed on the Docker website.

After following the instructions on Microsoft's website to create an Azure SQL Edge instance on Docker, the container would run fine for a while (less than an hour) and randomly stop with an error in the logs:

```
2022-12-13 12:47:21.16 spid51      Setting database option READ_WRITE to ON for database 'MyDatabase'.
This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Tue Dec 13 13:02:11 2022
The following diagnostic information is available:

         Reason: 0x00000006
        Message: Kernel bug check
        Address: 0x3fffb523be90
     Parameters: 0x830cce240
    Stack Trace:
                 file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000030E879
                 file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000030C809
                 file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000023BEEB
                 file:///windows/System32/Drivers/Afd.sys+0x0000000000006375
                 file:///windows/System32/Drivers/Afd.sys+0x000000000000685F
                 file:///windows/System32/Drivers/Afd.sys+0x000000000000630A
                 file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x00000000002412B6
                 file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000202FE2
                 file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000347978
                 file:///Windows/system32/mswsock.dll+0x00000000000015EC
                 file:///Windows/SYSTEM32/WS2_32.dll+0x000000000000A6BE
                 file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x000000000040E540
                 file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x000000000040EDB4
                 file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x000000000001CD9D
                 file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x000000000001B6F1
                 file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x00000000003584EC
                 file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x0000000000358F5A
                 file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x0000000000358A7F
                 file:///binn/sqldk.dll+0x000000000000A527
                 file:///binn/sqldk.dll+0x000000000000A6BD
                 file:///binn/sqldk.dll+0x000000000000A2DE
                 file:///binn/sqldk.dll+0x000000000003A122
                 file:///binn/sqldk.dll+0x000000000003A5F0
                 file:///binn/sqldk.dll+0x000000000003A4A9
                 file:///Windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL+0x0000000000014414
                 file:///windows/system32/ntdll.dll+0x0000000000075541
                 <unknown>+0x000000004CFDE800
        Process: 23 - sqlservr
         Thread: 159 (application thread 0x1c8)
    Instance Id: 64594cc2-b752-436d-aa56-298d20a76d00
       Crash Id: 37c2a3c7-542b-4513-ab2a-849165e9e990
    Build stamp: 664bcd7bdce4ea90c7e3aaf99680f41b973cd3ea43047cc8f440105d1382df75
   Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
     Processors: 1
   Total Memory: 1038999552 bytes
      Timestamp: Tue Dec 13 13:02:11 2022
     Last errno: 11
Last errno text: Resource temporarily unavailable
Capturing a dump of 23
FAILED to capture a dump. Details in paldumper log.
Executing: /opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh with parameters
     handle-crash.sh
     /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
     23
     /opt/mssql/bin
     /var/opt/mssql/log/
     
     64594cc2-b752-436d-aa56-298d20a76d00
     37c2a3c7-542b-4513-ab2a-849165e9e990
     
     

Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Capturing core dump and information to /var/opt/mssql/log...
/bin/cat: /proc/23/maps: Permission denied
/bin/cat: /proc/23/environ: Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: '/proc/23/map_files': Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/find: '/proc/23/map_files': Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/find: '/proc/23/map_files': Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/find: '/proc/23/map_files': Operation not permitted
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/timeout: failed to run command '/bin/journalctl': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/timeout: failed to run command '/bin/journalctl': No such file or directory
Tue Dec 13 13:02:13 UTC 2022 Capturing program information
Tue Dec 13 13:02:13 UTC 2022 Attempting to capture a dump with paldumper for pid 23
WARNING: Capture attempt failure detected
Attempting to capture a filtered dump with paldumper for pid 23
WARNING: Attempt to capture dump failed.  Reference /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.23.temp/log/paldumper-debug.log for details
Tue Dec 13 13:02:13 UTC 2022 Attempting to capture a dump with gdb
WARNING: Unable to capture crash dump with GDB. You may need to
allow ptrace debugging, enable the CAP_SYS_PTRACE capability, or
run as root.
Tue Dec 13 13:02:13 UTC 2022 Capturing program binaries
Tue Dec 13 13:02:13 UTC 2022 Not compressing the dump files, moving instead to: /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.12_13_2022_13_02_11.23.d
```

Comment: welcome to dba.se

Comment: I can see on the log things like: permission denied - operation not permitted and this is all happening when you want to set a database to read-write.

Comment: double check the account that you are running the installation under, double check the permissions of the sql server service account and make sure sql has access to whatever driver that database has files in.